# PHP script still runs after window is closed?

Tags: php, sleep

This is really weird. I have a php script and i intentionally added a 60 second sleep. I run the script for three seconds and close my browser window. Somehow it still performs it functions, but with a 60 second delay ..even after the window is closed.

can someone explain how this is possible

Comment: If you're running this under a webserver, PHP will not stop itself until it attempts to perform output and notices that the remote client has gone away.

Comment: The script runs on the server not the browser.

Comment: check [`Connection handling`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php)

Comment: PHP scripting is server side. So only after the script finishes execution, output/content is rendered on your browser. And closing browser makes no difference to execution. It runs on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that your browser is opened or closed makes no difference. Once the PHP process has started, it will keep running until it ends. Browser or no browser.

It's the same as asking "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?".

Answer (score 2):

You can actually control it, but yes - PHP checks user abort only on output attempt

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php